# Java: How to ensure byte array of size 2 after Hex to binary conversion?

Tags: java, binary, hex

*What I am doing*:

I have a hex value string `strHexVal`, which I am assigning to a byte array `hexBytes` using `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(strHexVal)`

*What I want*

The byte array `hexBytes` should always be of size `2` i.e. if after conversion the size of `hexBytes` is 1, I would like to insert the array with 0 and if the size after conversion is more than 2, throw an error

Can anyone help me with this?

Code:

```
String strHexVal= "15";
byte[] hexBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(strHexVal);

**Need help with this part:**
if ( hexBytes length is 1) {
   hexBytes[1] = hexBytes[0]
   hexBytes[0] = 0x00; //will this work???
}
else if (hexBytes.length > 2) {
   throw error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't just do `hexBytes[0] = 0x00;` because Java arrays have a fixed size once they are created.

You have to create a new `byte[]`:

```
if ( hexBytes.length == 1) {
    hexBytes = new byte[] { 0, hexBytes[0] };
}
```

Make sure you decide what to do if `hexBytes.length` is 0 as well. This will be the case if the input string is empty.